# Convert a nested for in a simple one

Tags: java, math

I have a new question about number generation, the problem starts from this piece of code:

```
for(int i = a1; i<n;i+=s1){
   for(int j = a2; j<m;j+=s2){
      for(int k = a3; k<f;k+=s3){
          ....
             doCalculation(new double[]{i,j,k})
```

As you can see i have some for-loops nested whose number is not fixed and nether the ranges are fixed.  I am wondering if there is a function that can turn the above piece of code in something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n*m*f*...;i++){
     doCalculation(evaluateParameters(i))
```

Quite solved with the answer of Bruce

```
doCalculations(0, new int[3], new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{7,5,5}, new int[]{2,1,3});

static void doCalculations(int current, int[] params, int[] starts, int[] 
    limits, int[] incrementers) {
    if(current == limits.length) return;
    if(current==0){ // initialize with default values
        params = new int[]{1,2,3};
    }
    for(int i = starts[current]; i <= limits[current]; i += incrementers[current]) {
        int tmp = params[current];
        params[current] = i;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(params));

        doCalculations(current + 1, params, starts, limits, incrementers);
        params[current] = tmp;
    }
}
```

But still does not work, see the output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 5, 3]
[1, 5, 3]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
[3, 3, 3]
[3, 4, 3]
[3, 4, 3]
[3, 5, 3]
[3, 5, 3]
...
```

EDIT 2: Object oriented version of the algo:

```
public class PriceEntity {

    static void doCalculations(List<SingleParameter> parameters) {
        doCalculations(0, null, parameters);
    }

    static void doCalculations(int current, int[] params, List<SingleParameter> parameters) {
        if(current == parameters.size()) return;
        if(params==null){ // initialize with default values
            params = new int[parameters.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) params[i] = parameters.get(i).getStart();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(params));
            doCalculations(current, params, parameters);
            return;
        }
        //System.out.println("Current is: "  + current);
        SingleParameter parameterToIncrement = parameters.get(current);
        for(int i = parameterToIncrement.getStart() i <= parameterToIncrement.getStop(); i += parameterToIncrement.getIncrement()) {
            int tmp = params[current];
            params[current] = i;

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(params));

            doCalculations(current + 1, params, parameters);
            params[current] = tmp;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <SingleParameter> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
        parameters.add(new SingleParameter(1,5,1));  // 5
        parameters.add(new SingleParameter(2,6,2));  // 3
        parameters.add(new SingleParameter(2,5,3));  // 1
        parameters.add(new SingleParameter(4,12,4)); // 3
        doCalculations(parameters);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor public class SingleParameter {

    private int start, stop, increment;
}
```

But still does not work

```
[1, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 2, 8]
[1, 2, 2, 12]
[1, 2, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 5, 12]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 8]
[1, 4, 2, 12]
[1, 4, 5, 4]
[1, 4, 5, 4]
[1, 4, 5, 8]
[1, 4, 5, 12]
[1, 6, 2, 4]
[1, 6, 2, 4]
[1, 6, 2, 4]
[1, 6, 2, 8]
[1, 6, 2, 12]
...... 140 records
```

Comment: Well, sure, you can divide/use `%` appropriately. The question is why you'd want to: multiple loops is much clearer.

Comment: I do not know the number of loop cycles, they depends on the variables. How can i "divide/use % appropriately" in this case?

Comment: "I do not know the number of loop cycles" Why do you need to? You've specified your guard conditions.

Comment: This algorithm is a part of a bigger one. The aim is that the user input the number of parameters and the range for each one and the system would evaluate all combinations, is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java `for` loops don't support looping over multi-dimensional structures.

This is a recursive method which will emulate n-nested `for` loops.

Note that params is a clone of starts, because otherwise the first calls to `doCalculation()` would be passed a mostly uninitialized array, in this case `[4, 0, 0]`, where `4` is the first element in `starts`.

```
int[] starts = new int[]{4, 5, 6};
int[] limits = new int[]{7, 8, 10};
int[] incrementers = new int[]{1, 2, 3}; // elements cannot be <= 0
int[] params = starts.clone(); // must be a clone of starts

doCalculations(starts, limits, incrementers, params, 0);
```

---

```
void doCalculations(int[] starts, int[] limits, int[] incrementers, int[] params, int current) {
    if(current == limits.length) {
        return;
    }
    for(int i = starts[current]; i < limits[current]; i += incrementers[current]) {
        params[current] = i;

        if(current == params.length - 1) {
            doCalculation(params);
        }

        doCalculations(starts, limits, incrementers, params, current + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You made my day bro, thank you so much! I just changed come code to add a custom "start" but it does not work... ;( could you help me?

Comment: To add a custom start, you will need to add an `int[] starts` which will contain the starting values, and be passed to all recursive calls. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I did the same but it does not work, see the edit of the question ;)

Comment: You only want to run the calculation on the last level of the recursion. 
            `if(current == params.length - 1) {
                doCalculation(params);
            }`

Comment: I Cannot understand you

Comment: See the updated answer.

Basically, it was running `doCalculate` as though it was placed between each n-nested `for` loop. Instead, you only want to run it in the last nested loop.

Comment: Ok ok now I understood, thank you Bruce! ASAP I will turn this utility in a library, it is too useful!

Answer (score 2):

If the count of loops is not fixed, you should use a recursion. It can be called to any depth.

```
void calc(List<Integer> params, int loopsCount, int[] loopLimits)
    int limit = loopLimits[loopsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        params.add(i);
        if (loopsCount == 0) doCalculation(params)
        else calc(params, loopsCount - 1, loopLimits);
        params.removeLast();
    }
}
```

Of course, you can make it in one for loop by having an array of limits `limits`, multiplying all of its members, and run a loop up to the final product. But then you will lose the information of each index, so you would need to compute it and store in an temporary array, such es

```
int product = limits[0] * limits[1] * ... * limits[n];
...
int[] indexes = new int[n];
for (i = 0; i < product; i++) {
    doCalculation(indexes);
    increaseIndex = 0;
    while(true) {
         if (indexes[increaseIndex]++ == limits[increaseIndex])
             indexes[increaseIndex++] = 0;
         else break;
    } 
}
```

but this is unlegible and unclear. However, maybe faster then recursion.